# Use $ \ \nabla f(3,2) \ $ to find a vector normal to the curve at $ \ (3,2)\ $

Tags: tangent-line

View the curve $ \ (y-x)^2+2=xy-3 \ $ as a contour of $ \ f(x,y) \ $

Use $ \ \nabla f(3,2) \ $ to find a vector normal to the curve at $ \ (3,2)\ $

**Answer:**

Let $ \ f(x,y)=(y-x)^2-xy+5=0 \ $

Then,

$ \nabla f(x,y)=\left\langle f_x,f_y \right\rangle \ = \left\langle 2(x-y)-y,2(y-x)-x \right\rangle $

Therefore,

$ \nabla f(3,2)=\left\langle0,-5 \right\rangle \ $ , which is normal t the level curves but not on the curve  $ \ f(x,y) \ $

How to find find the vector normal to the curve $ \ f(x,y) \ $ using $ \ \nabla f(3,2) \ $ ?

Help me doing this.

Comment: You’ve already done it.

Comment: what is the normal vector to the curve $ \ f(x,y) \ $ ? Because $ \ \nabla f(3,2) \ $ is not normal to $ \ f(x,y) \ $  but normal to the level curve as given in the question .

Comment: Remember that vectors really only have a direction and length, you can move them around as you please (you don't need to have the starting point on the curve).

Comment: “View the curve ... as a contour of $f(x,y)$.”

Comment: the answer is not correct  which show incorrect. what would be the vector normal to $ f(x,y) \ $ at $ \ (3,2) \ $ ?

Comment: Your phrase “the curve $f(x,y)$” is nonsensical: $f(x,y)$ is not a curve; $f(x,y)=0$ is. You’ve already found a normal to this curve. What is it that you’re really asking?

Comment: I have put the answer in the answer box but it shows incorrect. The question says we have to use $ \ \nabla f(3,2) \ $ to find the normal vector to the curve $ \ f(x,y)=0 \ $.

Comment: There is an infinite number of normal vectors to the curve at that point. You’ve correctly identified one. You now need to figure out what your course material means by **the** normal vector. Perhaps it’s insisting on a unit vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a graph of your curve, plotted by Maple.[image]

It shows clearly that the curve is horizontal at $(3,2)$, so the normal is vertical, so your answer is correct and the software marking it is wrong.

The only suggestion I could make is that any vertical vector is normal to the curve at this point, that is, any vector $(0,b)$ with $b\ne0$.  Try a unit vector, $(0,1)$ or $(0,-1)$ and see if that gets marked correct.